When signing a lease for a rental, is the landlord required to give you a copy with both signatures?
I ask, because I never got a copy of the lease that I signed when I moved in.  I read it at the time, and it was long and full of legalese, but seemed generally standard and OK.  I signed, paid the deposit, moved in, but I never got a copy of the lease with both our signatures.
Should I have?   Can I request it after the fact (correction, as I can always ask, what I want to know is, am I legally entitled to a copy with both signatures if I ask for one.
I've been here two years but looking at moving, which the landlord knows due to a conversation and he's been noticeably unfriendly towards me ever since.

No, there is no law stating you must get  a copy, if you already have one. The one you have should not be different than any other copy of it.
Not all leases are signed by two parties.

"if you already have one" -- but they don't already have one. There's only one copy, and the landlord has it.
